# Function to iterate through a nested list and append other lists isn't functioning properly

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I am currently trying to write a function to iterate through a nested list and check if one item from the list, 'team', is already in a separate list 'teams'.

- If it is not, I want to append a nested list, 'player_values' with a different item from the original nested list that was examined, in the form of a new list in the nested list.
- If it is, I want to append the nested list 'player_values' with the item from the original nested list, but I want to add it to the most recent list in the nested list 'player_values' instead of creating a new list.

Currently, my code looks like this :

```
def teams_and_games(list, player, idx):
teams = []
player_values = []
x = 0
y = -1

for rows in list:
    if player == list[x][BD.player_id] and list[x][BD.team] not in teams:
        teams.append(list[x][BD.team])
        player_values.append([list[x][idx]])
        x += 1   
        y += 1
    elif player == list[x][BD.player_id]:
        player_values[y].append(list[x][idx])
        x += 1

return player_values, teams
```

However, when I run the code in my main, using

```
    values, teams = teams_and_games(NiceRow, name, BD.games)
    print(values)
    print(teams)
```

It only prints empty lists. The fact that it prints empty lists shows that it is returning the correct variables, but I can't figure out why the code in the function is failing to add anything to the lists. I have tried switching the `.append` with a more simple `list +=` statement, but the result has been the same so far.

Ideally, I would be getting a nested list, containing an amount of lists equal to the number of items added to the other 'teams' list, and the list of teams in the order they were added.

The data I am working with is a nested list pulled from a .csv file, which has been formatted slightly using the .strip() and .split() commands. Each number has been converted to an int, and strings left as they are. The .CSV file it is from has 19 columns and ~80,000 rows, with each column always being either a string or an int.

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`--it overwrites a builtin function. Please show the data you're working with in your structures or a representative sample, along with expected/actual input/output. Thanks. It's a bit unusual to go `for rows in list:` and then never use `rows`. Using it would remove the need for `x`.

Comment: "I can't figure out why the code in the function is failing to add anything to the lists": you have an if/elif, and neither of the two tests is ever succeeding. You need to trace why that is.  At the very least, add an else: to that with a print or something so you can see why it didn't match what you clearly thought it was going to match. As @ggorlen hints, if you're iterating over an iterable but then using counter variables you have to increment manually, something isn't passing the smell test.